# How to disable the theme output from a Drupal module?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

I have a module which list the email address of the newsletter subscribers in website.I want to save those email id as CSV. but the following code gives a **header already sent error** because i don't know how to disable the theme from the module.

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-streamn"); 
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=$file");
readfile($tmpdir.$file);
```

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the drupal API for this?  See: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_set_header/6

Answer (score 1):

If you need to output non-themed and/or non-html from Drupal, you will have to do it from a module. In your page handler print your output instead of returning it. See for instance [`blogapi_rsd()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--blogapi--blogapi.module/function/blogapi_rsd/6).

Comment: Thanks for that link, I had no idea that you could make your own entire page without a theme.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use exit; so that execution will stop and Drupal doesn't get a chance to try and provide it's output.